# Linq Select Users which have the same cars

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have User objects and Car objects, they can have a many-to-many relationship via the Order object. I want to be able to get all users that have the same car(s) as user1. If I were writing this in SQL the following would yield the correct result

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE id IN (SELECT userId 
             FROM orders WHERE carId 
             IN (SELECT carId FROM orders WHERE userId = 1)
             )
AND id != 1
```

How do I do this using LINQ with a `List` of `Order`s and a `List` of `User`s?

My model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; }
}
```

My code:

```
 var orders = new List<Order>();
 orders.Add(new Order() { CarId = 1, UserId = 1 });
 orders.Add(new Order() { CarId = 1, UserId = 2 });
 orders.Add(new Order() { CarId = 2, UserId = 3 });
 orders.Add(new Order() { CarId = 2, UserId = 1 });
 orders.Add(new Order() { CarId = 3, UserId = 1 });
 orders.Add(new Order() { CarId = 4, UserId = 3 });

 var usersHasAnyCars = new Dictionary<int,int[]>();

 foreach (var user1 in orders.GroupBy(q=>q.UserId))
 {
         foreach (var user2 in usersHasAnyCars[user1.Key])
         {
            //my logic 
            //all users which have any car from cars of user1
         }
 }
```

For example:

- for user id = 1 result is user id=2 and id=3
- for user id = 2 result is user id=1
- for user id = 3 result is user id=1

The solution must be very fast, because I have a lot of data.
The best solution will be using LINQ.

Comment: what you are actually looking for?

Comment: Your code doesn't populate `usersHasAnyCars`

Comment: How to get list of users, which have any car from cars user1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace your 2 foreach for just this:

`var usersHasAnyCars = orders.GroupBy(x => x.UserId).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());`

### Update

In response your comment, you can get users that has cars that belongs to User1, like this:

```
var carsFromUser1 = orders.Where(o => o.UserId == 1).Select(o => o.CarId);
var usersHasAnyCars = orders.Where(o => carsUser1.Contains(o.CarId) && o.UserId != 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this give me cars of users, I want to iterate over users, which have at least one car from cars of User1

Comment: haha while clarifying the question you updated the answer independently great minds think alike

Comment: @wal92 the answer worked ? If it is, could you please mark as the correct